# custom action in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a simple link that will toggle my "status" attribute in my model from "pending" to "active".  For example, when I first create a user, I set the status to "pending".  Then when I show the list of users, I add a button that should change that user's status to "active".  I tried this via a custom action (is this a good approach?) but I'm having trouble with the auto-generated named route.

in my user index.html.haml:
`button_to "Manually Activate", activate_user_path`

in routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
  get :activate, :on => :member
```

in users_controller.rb:

```
 def activate
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attribute(:status, 'Active')
    redirect_to @user
  end
```

this seems to work when I go to say, /users/1/activate, as the status will update.  However, the /users page doesn't show and gives me error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError in Users#index
No route matches {:action=>"activate", :controller=>"users"}
```

ie, it is having a problem with the activate_user_path I specified in my view.  (However if I use another named-routes-style path that I haven't specified in my routes.rb to test it out, I get

```
NameError in Users#index
undefined local variable or method `blahblah_user_url' for #<#<Class:0x00000102bd5d50>:0x00000102bb9588>
```

so it seems that it knows it's in the routes.rb but something else is wrong? I'm really new to rails and would appreciate the help!
thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your link should look like this:

```
button_to "Manually Activate", activate_user_path(@user)
```

You need to add what user you want to activate.

Comment: oh, of course. thanks! (also, I changed button_to to link_to, since I think those make get requests only, as I specified in routes.rb.  button_to seems to work if you specify 'post' in routes.rb though)

Answer (score 6):

A number of problems, I can see.
Firstly you should NOT update the database using a GET request. 
Secondly button_to will provide you with an inplace form which when clicked will POST to your app.
Thirdly, the way you have your routes setup, you need to provide the user in the path (you've tested it by forming the url in the browser already).

run

```
rake routes
```

on the command prompt to see how your routes look and the name you can use to generate those routes.

I suspect you need to use

```
button_to "Manually Activate", activate_user_path(user)
```

(user or @user or whatever is the user object). In your button_to call and change the "get" to "post" in the routes file.

```
resources :users do
  member do
    post :activate
  end
end
```

Comment: yeah, I had problems with the get/post thing, I think because of a half-ass switching to jquery from prototype.  I don't really know js so I wasn't going to fiddle around with it yet, but jquery looked like the way to go for some other things I wanted to do, but right now it's as if javascript is disabled so all the post requests degrade into gets.  thus if i want to use post, i need button_to (which sends a post request), and also change the routes.rb to say post.  but it also works if i use a get request and a normal link.

Comment: RESTful design states that requests that change the database (like your activate action) should not be made using the GET verb. Regardless of use of Javascript, i would recommend that your view, continue to use the button_to  and ensure your routes only accept POST for the activate action (technically it should only be PUT, since POST is used for creation and PUT for updates).

Comment: Sorry the previous comment got posted half-way.

Comment: So did the next one. Never press enter in the comment box! So regardless of jquery or prototype, you must have correct semantic html. Since you are using Rails 3, things have become more unobtrusive. Meaning the Rails view helpers do not spit out javascript in your html like they used to in Rails 2.x. The rails.js (prototype version or jquery version) ensure that the correct verbs are used when sending request to the server. Do let us know what problems you are having with JS. It should really work out of the box (so to speak)!

Comment: ah yeah, i did not have my js set up properly. works now, thanks!